# CONNECT WALLET BUTTON PHANTOM INTO WIX

Tags: phantom

I'm using wix to develop my website and i tried to use it as dapp, but integrating a connect phantom wallet button doesn't work. Code is this:

````
<html lang="it">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Connetti a Phantom Wallet</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="connect-button">Connetti a Phantom Wallet</button>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@phantom/web3@latest/dist/phantom.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  const phantom = new Phantom();

  const connectButton = document.getElementById("connect-button");

  connectButton.addEventListener("click", async () => {
    try {
      // Richiesta di connessione al portafoglio Phantom
      await phantom.connect();

      // Il tuo codice JavaScript da eseguire quando il portafoglio è connesso
      console.log("Connesso a Phantom Wallet!");

      // Esempio: mostra l'indirizzo del portafoglio
      const address = await phantom.getAddress();
      document.getElementById("address").textContent = address;
    } catch (error) {
      // Gestione degli errori di connessione
      console.error("Errore durante la connessione a Phantom Wallet:", error);
    }
  });
  </script>

  <p id="address"></p>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Can you please remove caps lock and format your code using tags ``` or the code button. Also would be good if you could translate the comments to english. More people will be able to understand it here.